# Google Forms: Can I create a public website than can access a private form?

Tags: google-docs-api

My employer uses Google Apps (an enterprise edition, not the free version).  I would like to create a form that can not be accessed using the URL alone.  The form would be accessed either by logging into the google apps account, or through a website open to the public.  Is this possible?

I've tried researching the google apis, the new service accounts and authentication/authorization protocols, which sound promising, but I can't be sure if something like this is currently supported.

Thanks for any help,
Ann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant Not open to the public, well then just create an intranet for the company and then the company only has access, enable a VPN if you need access from home or elsewhere, but can be hard to setup.  I do not think google will allow you to add a URL.

Comment: I meant open to the public.  In my website I would perform some initial validation on the user, and then send him over to the google form.  I would want this to be the only way to access the form outside of logging into the google apps account.  Not sure what you meant by google not allowing me to add a URL.

Comment: Ok misinterpreted that, but the only thing you can do is restrict it to the domain. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/d0C4CNeqbP0 says that it is not possible to do more than that.

Comment: I was hoping that using code, I could get my web app to send authentication credentials to Google and then Google would respond by authorizing the web app to access the form.  I don't think this is possible.  I'm going to accept this answer.